# Site Design/Site Template/Site Script

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-design, site-script

Currently I am configuring A LOT of site designs and site scripts to help with the creation of "Site Templates" in SharePoint online.  I am doing well with the both of these but the question I have is that for the template I have several list that come with data already in the lists.  I have the Site Designs built that create the list, but I am wondering if there is a way to have the content pre-filled in the list?

I am happy to do this via flow, but I need a way to automate the entire process so that when they do a self service site creation all of the default lists/libraries are in place and those with content are pre-populated.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-fill a list using the [PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine).
Then you can [call the PnP provisioning engine from a site script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning).

You can find [here](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Provisioning-Schema) provisioning template samples.

Comment: As mentioned before I dont know how to use this that is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a site script action "triggerFlow" that triggers a flow automatically when the site design is applied. You can use that flow to populate the lists.
You can follow this example:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-trigger-flow-tutorial